# after index 2 i am getting NaN in fibonacci series

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

In my javascript code I am getting NaN after the index 2, like if I am taking `5` as input then I am getting `[0,1,NaN,NaN,NaN]` and I am not getting why I am getting this NaN and what does it signify as answer

```js
var a = [];

var n = prompt("enter a number: ");

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    a.push(0);
  }

  if (i === 2) {
    a.push(1);
  } else if (i > 2) {
    var num1 = a[i - 1];
    var num2 = a[i - 2];
    var num3 = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];

    a.push(num3);
  }
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Debug it `else if(i>2) { console.log(i, a[i-1], a[i-2]);` (Also is your shift key broken?)

Comment: your array indexes are off by one compared with i. The first time you get `a[i-1]` you're getting undefined. Then when you try to add num2, you get NaN. Afterwards, you are always doing undefined + NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes start from zero.
Try this:

```js
    var a = [];
    
    var n=prompt("enter a number: ");
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      if (i < 2) {
        a.push(1);
      } else {
        var num1 = a[i - 1];
        var num2 = a[i - 2];
        var num3 = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    
        a.push(num3);
      }
    }
    
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You had to begin with `i=0` and `i<n` and decrease all index about 1.

```js
var a=[];

var n=prompt("enter a number: ");
        for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i===0)
            {
                a.push(0);
            }
    
            if(i===1)
            {
                a.push(1);
            }
            
            else if(i>1){
                var num1=a[i-1];
                var num2=a[i-2];
                var num3=a[i-1]+a[i-2];

               a.push(num3);
            }
        }
   
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is in this piece: `var num3 = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];`. Updating it to `var num3 = a[i - 2] + a[i - 3];` will fix, as you are starting counter index variable with 1, but array location index starts with 0.

Update you code to:

```js
let a = [];
let n = prompt("enter a number: ");

if (n >= 1) {
  a.push(0);
}
if (n >= 2) {
  a.push(1);
}

for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    a.push(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2]);
}

console.log(a);
```